# Ajax doesn't perform a fresh request when prompted

Tags: php, ajax

I'm still learning Ajax and each time I want to change the page content using ajax i use the script below:

```
function load_page(id)
{
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    var toId = "";

    $('#ajax-intro-body').show();

    if (id == "dashboard")
        toId = "../src/pages/partials/" + id + ".php";
    else
        toId = "../src/pages/" + id + ".php";

    $.ajax({
        url:toId,
        method:"POST",
        cache: false,
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        data:{},
        success:function(data)
        {
         if (data == "session_expired"){
             location.replace("../src/pages/login/")
         }else{
              // Show output data
              $('#ajax-content').html(data);
              // Set refresh address id
              $('.refresh-content').attr('id',id);
              // Fade out the loading bar body
              $('#ajax-intro-body').fadeOut(100);
              // Remove animation from sync
              $('#refresh-icon').removeClass("fa-spin");
         }
        }
    });
}
```

So i think that the code is pretty easy to understand. Now i got a "project page" where you can also delete it , this page is being loaded using the script up there and i got the following code in php:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
        if (isset($_GET['id'])){ 

        $("#dialog-3").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,//remove this and the click to aut open
        bgiframe: true,
        width: 340,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
                "Delete":function(){
                        $(this).dialog("close");

                        $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "../src/requests/deleteproject.php",
                                data: {
                                    id: <?php echo $projectid; ?>,
                                    flag: true,
                                },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    load_page('projects/listprojects');
                                }
                        });

                },
                Cancel: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                }
        }
});
}
}
```

So you can see that i'm trying to perform and ajax request inside the project page if i want to delete it. Using the browser network tab i can see that actually the GET parameter id is being changed into the right number when i call the project page but actually it doesn't update the ID `id: <?php echo $projectid; ?>,`. I've read that i need to set the cache to *false* inside the ajax request but it doesn't seem to work so i can't update the Id.

Do you guys have any idea ? THANK YOU!

Comment: Are you sure you can mix js and php code like you do?

Comment: that PHP code appears to be for GET requests but your ajax method is POST. Is that the actual PHP or just extracts from it with vital pieces missing?

Comment: @u_mulder yes you can do this.

Comment: @RamRaider You're also right, i fixed and set all using POST request but the problems persists, i thought that your solution was correct but the only moment when the ID changes is when i refresh the page using CTRL + R. Otherwise if i delete a project and then i create a new one the page still points to delete the previous one.

Comment: I've also performed some tests setting up an hidden input with the new id and it seems to work but for some reasons i can't assign the ID dynamically using php to JS from the second time on.